# How can I pass java system property to jetty?

Tags: java, jetty, system-properties

How can I pass a system property to jetty startup something like -DSERVER="localhost"
if it is in start.config what is the exact syntax ?
and will it be available to my deployed war with this `System.getProperty("SERVER"`) ?

thnx in advance

Comment: Why?  I would not want Jetty to be dependent on such a thing.  Seems wrong to me.

Comment: Are you using embedded Jetty?

Comment: I do not want to run to config files as it will be included in the war file ..it means that I should re-compile or at least re archive the war file for every case .
I do not use embedded Jetty .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the /etc/jetty/start.config 
and add SERVER="127.0.0.1" in the start if the file.

Comment: Which version of jetty does this apply to - the file doens't seem to be there in jetty 8.x?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put something like this in `start.ini`?

```
--exec
-DSERVER="localhost"
```

(perhaps before `OPTIONS=`, but I'm not sure that's necessary.)

The comments in `start.ini` say:

> If the arguements in this file include
>   JVM arguments (eg -Xmx512m) or JVM
>   System properties (eg com.sun.???),
>   then these will not take affect unless
>   the --exec parameter is included [...]

Comment: Thx Bruno
but I do not have start.ini file any where
Hint I use jetty 6 /Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming Jetty 7.